# True basic password generator

Tags: basic

How can I create a 8-digit password generator with letters(upper case characters, lower case characters), numbers and special characters using true Basic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function generatePassword(passwordLength) {
  var numberChars = "0123456789";
  var upperChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var lowerChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var allChars = numberChars + upperChars + lowerChars;
  var randPasswordArray = Array(passwordLength);
  randPasswordArray[0] = numberChars;
  randPasswordArray[1] = upperChars;
  randPasswordArray[2] = lowerChars;
  randPasswordArray = randPasswordArray.fill(allChars, 3);
  return shuffleArray(randPasswordArray.map(function(x) { return x[Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length)] })).join('');
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}

alert(generatePassword(12));
```